# Given a numerical sequences like 1,3,13,31,57,91..how does one (or wolfram alpha for example) determine a general formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Predict next number from a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144881/predict-next-number-from-a-series)

I gave wolfram alpha the sequence: $1,3,13,31,57,91,133,183,241$ and it told me a possible closed form would be $4n^2 -10n + 7$ (which turned out to be right for where I was getting the sequence from). What are some ways of doing this given some terms? I have seen recurrences being approached with power series to find generating functions, but don't recall seeing methods for going from some terms into a possible closed form. What are some approaches?

Comment: For the specific problem of finding a low-degree polynomial, take finite differences until the finite differences appear constant. For the general problem, it depends very strongly on what kind of rule you expect to generate the sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on Qiaochu Yuan's comment let us take finite differences until the finite differences appear constant.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
 a_n & b_n &c_n \\ \hline
1  \\ \hline
&3-1=2\\ \hline
3&&10-2=8   \\ \hline
& 13-3=10\\ \hline
13&&18-10=8  \\ \hline
&31-13=18\\ \hline
31&&26-18=8  \\ \hline
&57-31=26\\ \hline
57 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
I.e. Let $a_n$ be the sequence in question. Let $b_n$ be the difference between two consecutive terms in $a_n$ and let $c_n$ be the difference between two consecutive terms in $b_n$. Working backwards we get that $$\begin{align*}b_n&=b_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_k \\
a_n&=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k\end{align*}$$
Since $c_n=8$ and $b_1=2$
$$b_n=b_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_k=2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}8=2+8(n-1)=8n-6$$
Finally, using $b_n$ we can find $a_n$
$$a_n=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(8k-6)=1+8\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}6$$
$$=1+8\left(\frac{(n-1)(1+n-1)}{2}\right)-6(n-1)=4(n^2-1)-6n+7=\fbox{$4n^2-10n+7$}$$

Comment: Thank you, very detailed response.